# Get a triangle’s angles from the sides

Tags: functions, function-construction, homework

Hint: For the SSS case, you are given the 3 sides a, b, and c, and need to find the corresponding angles α, β, and γ. To find α, for example, you solve the equation `a^2==b^2+c^2-2b c Cos[α]` for the variable `α`. There will be 2 outputs, and the positive output will be your solution.

Now use that solution to create the function `α[a_,b_c,_]:= (the output you obtained)*180/π//N (multiplying by 180/\[DoubledPi]` will convert the angle from radians to degrees and postfixing //N will give an approximation to the angle). Do the same for β and γ. (For β you will solve the equation `b^2==a^2+c^2-2a c Cos[β]` for β, and use a similar equation to solve for γ).

You can then create the function `sss[a_,b_,c_]:={α[a,b,c], β[a,b,c], γ[a,b,c], a, b, c}]` which has input the 3 sides and as output the 3 angles and the 3 sides. Check your work by doing Example 2.

this is the given hint my professor provided.

```
Reduce[a^2 == b^2 + c^2 - 2 b c Cos[α]] 
a == -Sqrt[b^2 + c^2 - 2 b c Cos[α]] || 
a == Sqrt[b^2 + c^2 - 2 b c Cos[α]]
f[α[a_, b_, c_] := 
Sqrt[b^2 + c^2 - 2 b c Cos[α]]*180/π // N]
f[Null]
```

This is as far as I've got. I don't think I'm using the proper code.

Comment: Note Mathematica has primitives like `SSSTriangle` which work with symbolic inputs: `$Assumptions = Thread[{a, b, c} > 0];
t = SSSTriangle[a, b, c];
Simplify[PolygonAngle[t] /. {Conjugate -> Identity, Abs -> Identity}]`

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`SSSTriangle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SSSTriangle.html) and [`TriangleMeasurement`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TriangleMeasurement.html) with the property `{"InteriorAngle", All}`:

```
ClearAll[αβγ]

αβγ[a_, b_, c_] := TriangleMeasurement[SSSTriangle[a, b, c], {"InteriorAngle", All}]


αβγ[a, b, c]
```

> ```
> {ArcCos[(-a^2 + b^2 + c^2)/(2 b c)], 
>  ArcCos[(a^2 - b^2 + c^2)/(2 a c)], 
>  ArcCos[(a^2 + b^2 - c^2)/(2 a b)]}
> ```

Comment: I am surprised over and over again about your knowledge of special Mathematica functions!

Comment: @Ulrich, thank you. Need those functions  because "don't know much about analytical geometry":)

Answer (score 2):

If we assume a triangle `a,b,c` ( counterclockwise) with opposite angles `α,β,γ` (as you did)  knowing  the law of cosines we have the list:

```
cosini[a_, b_, c_] := {
       (a^2 - b^2 - c^2)/(2 b c),
       (b^2 - a^2 - c^2)/(2 a c),
       (c^2 - a^2 - b^2)/(2 a b )} 

(* Cos[α], Cos[β], Cos[γ]} *)
```

For example, the angles of an equilateral triangle evaluate to:

```
cosini[1, 1, 1] // ArcCos

(* {(2 π)/3, (2 π)/3, (2 π)/3} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Reduce[{ a > 0 , b > 0 , c > 0, 0 < α < π , 
  0 < β < π, 0 < γ < π, 
  a^2 == b^2 + c^2 - 2*b*c*Cos[α], 
  b^2 == c^2 + a^2 - 2*c*a*Cos[β] , 
  c^2 == a^2 + b^2 - 
    2*a*b*Cos[γ] }, {α, β, γ}, Reals]// Simplify
```